# plink - Server refused our key - No supported authentication methods available

Tags: ssh, putty, public-key, private-key, plink

I am using a .ppk file with putty to connect to my AWS server. This works with no problems.

However, if I try to use the same .ppk file with plink then I get an error:

#### Attempt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh xyz@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com -P 22 -i "C:\Users\black\Documents\SSH\aws.ppk"
Using username "xyz".
```

#### Error:

```
Server refused our key
FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

Why does it work with putty, but not with plink?

---

I tried to extract my private key from the ppk by following the instructions seen [here](https://tecadmin.net/convert-ppk-to-pem-using-command), but it does not work. I get **unable to use key file**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated plink to the latest version, now it works.